# Mongomapper: "SQL JOIN" style in querying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

I have two models:

```
class TrackItem
  key :state, Integer, :default => 1

  many :track_jobs
end

class TrackJob
  key :invoke_at, Time

  belongs_to :track_item
end
```

I want make query with join:

```
item = TrackItem.create(:state => 1)
item.track_jobs.create(:invoke_at => Time.now)

TrackJob.where("track_item.state" => 1).all # => []
```

Return empty array. Where is problem?

MongoDB log:

```
MONGODB track_tweets_development['track_tweets.models.track_jobs'].find({:"track_item.state"=>1})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Ruby, but try this:

```
TrackItem.where(:state => 1).first.track_jobs # => should result in all specified track_jobs (so the one you created at line 2)
```

Since you're adding track-jobs as a embedded document, you can query the (parent) document. It'll automatically contain all your `track_jobs`.

Comment: TrackItem.where(:state => 1).first.track_jobs  - is inappropriate exemple for me. I need to get all jobs, not only by one item.

Comment: You do get all jobs you assigned to one `TrackItem`. It gets all `track_job`s assigned to one `TrackItem`. (You say it'ld get one `track_job` assigned to any `TrackItem`s.)